# Using a timer vs update to run game SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am curious what to use for my game. A timer:

```
let goodFPS = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 0.01666)
let mainGameRunner = SKAction.run {
//my code is here
}
let toRepeat = SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence([goodFPS,mainGameRunner]))
inGameHighScore.run(toRepeat,withKey:"mainGame")
```

or the update function:

```
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval){
//my code is here
}
```

Which provides faster more consistent updates?

note: my frame rate is in the range of 45 to 58

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First I think you are taking the FPS problem the wrong way around.  You cannot "force" a faster frame rate than the device can give you.  If you are basing the movements in your game on the assumption that every frame will be consistent, you are doing it wrong.  It's actually how they did in the early days because CPUs were so slow and the difference from one generation to the new one wasn't too bad at first.  But running an old DOS game on younger hardware will be tricky because the framerate is so high that the whole game mechanic becomes unstable or simply too fast to be playable.

The concept here is to think "over time" and to scale down any action in relation with the time elapsed between two frames.

The `update()` method gives you that opportunity by providing the current system clock state every frame.  By keeping track of the time on the last frame, you can calculate the time difference with the current frame and use that difference to scale down what you are doing.

Using a timer to get the update on a consistent frame rate is not recommended nor practical.  You may be calling the update closure at a given time interval, but the code inside that closure is taking time to execute on its own, and depending on your game logic, it might even have different execution times.  So maybe the pause timing is consistent, but the code running before and after that pause might not be consistent.  Then what happens if you run your game on a slower CPU?  The code speed will change even more, making your timing inaccurate.

Another point against using an `SKAction` for your game loop is simply what they are.  An action is an object in memory, meany to be reused by multiple objects.  If you are making a "jump" action, for example, it is recommended to store that action somewhere and to reuse the same object every time you need something that "jumps", no matter what node it is.  Your game loop is meant to be executed every frame, but not by different objects.  Actions are also disposable.  Meaning that you can kill an action even while it's running.  If you put your game loop in an action, it will probably be run by the `SKScene`.  If you use another action on your scene it becomes a puzzle right away because there are only two ways of removing an action besides letting it come to term: removing all actions or creating the action with an identifier key and use that key to remove any action with that key.  If you don't see it already, it then forces you to put identifiers on every action that will be run by the scene and remove them one by one.  And them again it leave a door open for a mistake that will get rid of your game loop because, keep it in mind, actions are DISPOSABLE!  Then there is also no guarantee that your action will get executed first every single frame.

Why use the `update()` method?  Simply because it is built IN your scene.  No matter what, every frame, `update()` gets called first.  THEN, the actions get executed.  You cannot flush the `update()` method accidentally like you can with an action.  You don't have to be careful about strong/weak relationships causing memory leaks because you are referring to objects from inside a closure like you do with an action.

**Suggested reads:**

1. [SKAction API reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skaction)
2. [SKScene API reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skscene) : read about the frame processing in `SpriteKit`.  It will help you understand how they put everything together at every frame.

I hope it makes things clearer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that SKAction's timing facilities are based on the same game loop that is calling `update`.

The advantage of SKAction is that it's fire and forget for you, while using `update` would get awkward with setting and checking a bunch of timer variables.

Comment: I've been testing the out and neither seems that great

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a ton of experience with `SpriteKit` but I do have some experience making games and animations in iOS.

There is a class called `CADisplayLink` that fires a call to a delegate every time the screen is refreshed, this is a great way to update the screen, either in a game or in an animation, because you can know it will be called every frame and no more.

I'm not sure if SpriteKit uses that class to fire the `update` method, but I'm sure it uses something similar. This is usually called the run loop.

`SKActions` run on top of this run loop.

By creating your own run loop using a `wait` action, not only you're not gaining any benefits, you could be introducing inconsistencies in the way your logic is run.

Imagine that you have your wait action set to `0.01` seconds (I rounded it down for simplicity). If the screen is refreshing faster than you expect, and the action is updated every `0.009` seconds, the first time it's checked, it won't fire because there's a remaining `0.001` second on the `wait` command, so another `0.009` seconds will pass, and your code will be executed after `0.018` seconds, instead of your desired `0.01`. Not only that, but two frames will have passed between the execution.

If you use the `update` function, you can know that your logic will be executed once every screen refresh, and no more.

Comment: hi Emilio - this is exactly what I want to know! is CADisplayLink just the same as Update in SpriteKit ?

Comment: @Fattie That's hard to tell but I'd say it's probably the same mechanism. I wouldn't use a custom `CADisplayLink` over `update()` though.